# Since Python doesn't have a switch statement, what should I use?

Tags: python, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replacements for switch statement in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

I'm making a little console based application in Python and I wanted to use a Switch statement to handle the users choice of a menu selection.

What do you vets suggest I use. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of all of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+switch.

Comment: See also question [switch case in python doesn't work; need another pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886641/switch-case-in-python-doesnt-work-need-another-pattern/3893242#3893242).

Comment: Since Python 3.10 there is a new `match/case` syntax called "Structural Pattern Matching".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dispatch tables, or rather dictionaries.

You map keys aka. values of the menu selection to functions performing said choices:

```
def AddRecordHandler():
        print("added")
def DeleteRecordHandler():
        print("deleted")
def CreateDatabaseHandler():
        print("done")
def FlushToDiskHandler():
        print("i feel flushed")
def SearchHandler():
        print("not found")
def CleanupAndQuit():
        print("byez")

menuchoices = {'a':AddRecordHandler, 'd':DeleteRecordHandler, 'c':CreateDatabaseHandler, 'f':FlushToDiskHandler, 's':SearchHandler, 'q':CleanupAndQuit}
ret = menuchoices[input()]()
if ret is None:
    print("Something went wrong!")
menuchoices['q']()
```

Remember to validate your input! :)

Comment: That code is so sexy I want to give it lingerie and have it pose on Playboy. +1

Comment: (1) Btw, `the_input in menu_choices` is a cheap validation that's guaranteed to be in synch with the actual choices. (2) All the example handlers return `None`, so don't bother the police after runnig the example ;) (3) As always, use `raw_input` instead of `input` in Python 2.

Answer (score 13):

There are two choices, first is the standard `if ... elif ...` chain.  The other is a dictionary mapping selections to callables (of functions are a subset).  Depends on exactly what you're doing which one is the better idea.

elif chain

```
 selection = get_input()
 if selection == 'option1':
      handle_option1()
 elif selection == 'option2':
      handle_option2()
 elif selection == 'option3':
      some = code + that
      [does(something) for something in range(0, 3)]
 else:
      I_dont_understand_you()
```

dictionary:

```
 # Somewhere in your program setup...
 def handle_option3():
    some = code + that
    [does(something) for something in range(0, 3)]

 seldict = {
    'option1': handle_option1,
    'option2': handle_option2,
    'option3': handle_option3
 }

 # later on
 selection = get_input()
 callable = seldict.get(selection)
 if callable is None:
      I_dont_understand_you()
 else:
      callable()
```

Comment: Can you give a simple example of how to use Dictionary mapping? Space_Cowboy's example isn't quite clear.

Comment: @sergio: suppose you have functions `opener` and `closer`, say to open and close a window. Then to call one of them based on a string, do `switcher = {"open": opener, "close": closer}` so that you have the actual functions in a `dict`. Then you can do `switcher[choice]()`.

Answer (score 9):

Use a dictionary to map input to functions.

```
switchdict = { "inputA":AHandler, "inputB":BHandler}
```

Where the handlers can be any callable. Then you use it like this:

```
switchdict[input]()
```