# Looking for a good replacement for elif & if , like switch case

Tags: python, if-statement, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replacements for switch statement in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Given this method :

```
def getIndex(index):
    if((index) < 10):
        return 5
    elif(index < 100):
        return 4
    elif(index < 1000):
        return 3
    elif(index < 10000):
        return 2
    elif(index < 100000):
        return 1
    elif(index < 1000000):
        return 0
```

I want to make it in a switch-case style , however , Python doesn't support switch case .

Any replacements for that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python - Check this out! :)

Comment: You can use `if` instead of `elif` everywhere in this code.

Comment: The reason Python doesn't have `switch` is that it's really, internally, exactly like your series of `elif` statements. Using the `elif` is essentially the same and more obvious what the logic is. It is already the preferred syntax for Python. There is no reason to change it.

Comment: See answers to the question [switch case in python doesn't work; need another pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886641/switch-case-in-python-doesnt-work-need-another-pattern).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about `6-len(str(index))`?

Answer (score 3):

the classic pythonic way is to use a dictionary where the keys are your tests and the values are callable functions that reflect what you intend to do:

```
def do_a():
    print "did a"

self do_b():
    print " did b"

#... etc

opts = {1:do_a, 2:do_b}

if value in opts: 
    opts[value]()
else:
    do_some_default()
```

Answer (score 2):

In this particular instance I would just use maths:

```
def get_index(index):
    return 6 - int(round(math.log(index, 10)))
```

You have to use the built-in function [`round`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) as `math.log` returns a float.